# Need to replace Search layout (when select Add Product from Opportunity) with new product picklist fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, product

Can any one help me with Visual force page and coding?
We need to replace standard Add product search layout and new search layout should have 5 picklist fields with AND  condition.

Anyone helps really appreciated.

Thanks indvance.

Comment: Hi sai, this type of question isn't encouraged here and will likely be closed. If you make an honest effort and get stuck, we'll be more likely to help you. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sai @sfdcfox is right.

But I can give you an idea of how to approach this problem without going to code.
1. Create a visual force page and a controller with all the respective fields in place.
2. For a dynamic query, create a string and append the conditions to the string accordingly.
3. create a method that will be called on the click of the search button, in that method you can use the string and query that dynamically formed string.

Comment: Hi @ sfdcfox , @ maruf , I agree with you , I tried and I got stuked . below is the code which tried

Comment: I tried creating a VF Page with picklist fields from Product2

Comment: SELECT Id,Name,Productcode,family,CanUseQuantitySchedule,CanUseRevenueSchedule FROM Product2 WHERE Product2.Generation__c  <> ' ' AND  Product2.Inboard_Lite__c <> ' ' AND  Product2.Laminate__c <> '  '

Comment: I was able to reach till I search but next step I need to give user product select with checkbox and When I search for product it is displaying all products instead it should display only with those picklist values selected . how to specify in my query only display  selected picklist values . after selecting i should be able to naviagate to other page to add quantity , date and price

Comment: One issue with this code is No products are getting displayed and I need add checkbox for product single and multi selection Please let me how to add checkbox before every product which is getting displayed after search and display selected products in next page

Answer (score 0):

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results" id="ResultsBlock">
        <apex:pageBlocksection columns="1">
        <apex:outputPanel id="out">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listclms}" var="clm" rendered="{!showResults}">
                <apex:column headerValue="Claim Name">
                    <apex:commandlink value="{!clm.Name}" action="/{!clm.id}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!clm.ProductCode}" headerValue="ProductCode"/>
               <!-- <apex:column value="{!clm.Description}" headerValue="Description"/> -->
                <apex:column value="{!clm.Family}" headerValue="Product Family"/>
                <apex:column value="{!clm.CanUseQuantitySchedule}" headerValue="Has Quantity Schedule"/>
                <apex:column value="{!clm.CanUseRevenueSchedule}" headerValue="Has Revenue Schedule"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> <br/>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!showNoResults}" value="No Records Found" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlocksection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

public with sharing class ProductController_AC {
 // public Integer minAmt{get;set;}
 // public Integer maxAmt{get;set;}
  public list listclms{get;set;}
   public boolean showResults{get;set;}
   public boolean  showNoResults{get;set;}
   public ProductController_AC(ApexPages.standardController objCtrl){
      system.debug('### Constructor running');
       listclms = new list();
       showResults=false;
       showNoResults=false;

}
   public void searchButtonClicked(){ 
    try{
         listclms = [SELECT Id,Name,Productcode,family,CanUseQuantitySchedule,CanUseRevenueSchedule FROM Product2 WHERE Generation__c  <> null  AND  Inboard_Lite__c =: null  AND  Laminate__c <> null ];
       if(listclms.size()>0){
         showResults=true;
         showNoResults=false;
       }
       else{
           showResults=false;
           showNoResults=true;
           system.debug('Please check');
         //  return listclms.errorMessage('Select all picklist values');

```
       //ClaimController_AC.showmessage('Please redefine your search criteria');
     }
     system.debug('### listAccs.size: '+listclms.size());
  }
  catch(Exception objException){
     system.debug('### objException: '+objException.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

public void clearButtonClicked(){ 
    showResults=false;
    showNoResults=false;
    listclms = new list();

}
    }